# COPY from file со стороны клиента PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Как сделать так, чтобы команда COPY загружала данные в базу из файла, который находится на стороне клиента, а не на стороне сервера?

Comment: Передать файл на сервер.

Comment: @bronstein87 psql -U postgres -d (имя базы) -f (имя файла)